# Remove Oracale SQL Modeler Database Design tables

Tags: oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have created a new database design using SQL Developer Modeler and using an existing database connection. I am not the designer but all I wanted to do is try and generate a generate a diagram as I do not have access to any other design tool, and yes I was playing with Data Modeler Tool. I did not realize that my design will actually be saved as part of schema itself. That is, list of tables in SQL Developer now shows a ton of DMRS_* (DMSRS_cONTACTS, DMRS_ENTITIES etc.) tables. I must remove this design and related tables quickly before confusing others and creating a mess!

Is there a way to delete this design completely? Can I drop these tables safely without affecting the original database?

Comment: Looks like I need to apply filtering to hide DMRS_* tables. Had to apply this to views too. Index has just too many and not sure what to filter. What is DMRS_* (wild card represents name)  table anyways? If someone could verify that I am on right track that would be great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Often, the canned reports that SQL*Developer gives you are completely insufficient for your needs.  When that happens, SQL*Developer gives you the opportunity to export your model to a reporting "schema" so that you can write SQL queries against the metadata in your model.  Those DMRS tables are that "schema".  When you're done with your reports, you can safely drop those tables.  If you ever need them again, SQL*Developer will create them again.

Comment: I was ablet to delete those tables safely right away. But thanks for your response with clear clarification.